# Cannot create entities into Cloud Firestore using Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a "car" object into Entities - Datastore into Firebase, but, when I create the 'car' object, and create a collection where I am adding this 'car', I am getting errors I can not find on the internet yet.

This is the code:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> dataToSave = {
'carName' : 'carName',
'carColor' : 'carColor',
'carPrice' : 100,
};

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('carCollection').add(dataToSave);
```

And these are the Errors:

```
W/DynamiteModule(11698): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(11698): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(11698): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
[OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The Cloud Firestore API is not available for Firestore in Datastore Mode database projects/PROJECT_NAME/databases/(default)., cause=null}
W/Firestore(11698): This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
[WriteStream]: (c3babd) Stream closed with status: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The Cloud Firestore API is not available for Firestore in Datastore Mode database projects/PROJECT_NAME/databases/(default)., cause=null}.
[WatchStream]: (16a48b2) Stream closed with status: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The Cloud Firestore API is not available for Firestore in Datastore Mode database projects/PROJECT_NAME/databases/(default)., cause=null}.
```

I looked all over the Youtube videos, and Flutter documentation, but I have not found something similar.

Comment: do you mean your 'dataToSave' does not been added to your carCollection in the write process in your question ?

Comment: I mean, I want my 'dataToSave' object to be stored in Google Cloud -> Entities, the same this episode ( minute 3:00 ) shows : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COZ67pwhguY

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code , also i tested it as well , it stored the data successfully , make sure that you setup Firestore correctly in your flutter project

Comment: one thing more , as what i understand from the message error , is that your project can not access to firstore , did you add google-services file to your app file ?

Comment: Yes, I have google-services.json added in android/app/, I ran flutterfire configure and I configured the project for Android, Ios and Web Dev, firebase --version ( works only in cmd, and in Android Studio gives me an error ) is 11.25.3. In pubsec.yaml, I have: firebase_database: ^10.1.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.4.0
  firebase_core: ^2.9.0

Comment: there is something wrong with your Firestore implementation setup . did you add required lines in gradle file that you firebase asked to ? like 'apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services''  ..  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3')
 
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0' ?? .. if not so add them and run flutter clean then run again

Comment: I can't figure out if I have passed through this setup, can you give me a video about these settings or some places which I can check out, or any documentation ?

Comment: Also, I have found something in Project Settings -> SDK setup and configuration, and I added what you've said: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'' .. implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3') implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0', but still no result. :(

Comment: visit your setting page in your firebase page , there they giving you instructions under see sdk instructions button of what you should add .. don't forget to flutter clean

Comment: I managed to solve the problem: The reality is that, I have had all the necesary components installed, including those from Project Settings, but somehow Firebase couldn't show me the Firebase Database, instead it was Google Cloud Store. So, I created a new database, and the problem was solved. So thanks a lot for being patient with me and checking all of the scenario cases. :)

Comment: glad to hear that , please post your answer , so others who stack on it find the solution